# Typescript property of object or null not working as expected

Tags: typescript, null, typescript-typings

I have this super simple case:

```
interface Image {
  src: string;
}

const image: Image|null = null;

const src = image.src;
```

**[StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-6wcz9e)**

Why do I not get any complaints that `"Object is possibly null"` from typescript?

Now I get runtime errors when accessing `src` in case `image` is null. Should typescript not help me catch this?

Comment: The editor doesn't have the strictNullChecks option on. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFs4HMUG8BQyyAzlAgFwlhShYDc+AvvvggPYjFjLCY6UZsEAD4gArgBsJyALzJxUhqw5cSZWTz4QAdKQR0gA)

Comment: @GuyIncognito thanks, exactly what I was looking for.